# Iterating array of objects in PHP

Tags: php, loops

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($prices); $i++){
error_log($prices[$i]->anObjectVariable);
}
```

or

```
foreach ($prices as $price){
error_log($price->anObjectVariable);
}
```

None of these seems to work, here are the errors I get:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: price::$anObjectVariable
```

this is the code which I use to prepare the object(s) and the array.

```
class price {

    public $anObjectVariable;

}

$prices = array();
    $p = new price();
    $p->anObjectVariable = "PRINT ME IN ERROR LOG!";
    array_push($prices, $p);
```

Comment: So, what's the question itself?

Comment: @metal_fan Presumably "why does PHP say that this property is not defined when it is part of the class definition."

Comment: `error_log($prices[i]->anObjectVariable);` should be `error_log($prices[$i]->anObjectVariable);`, I guess it's a typo ?

Comment: @romainberger Perhaps, but that wouldn't explain why the `foreach` variant also fails.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($prices)` and/or *any* other debugging?

Comment: Did you mean to use `error_log()`?  By default, that'll write the contents to your error log file, not the page.

Comment: var_dump($prices) works fine!
@romainberger - no, it's not a typo: I'll fix it now, thanks!

Comment: yes, I'm looking at both the web page and the error log.

Comment: Shouldn't you define `$prices` as an array before you use it in `array_push`?  As in `$prices = array();`

Comment: yeah, I forgot to insert it in the snippet but it is already defined as an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested it locally and the following code works fine if you define $prices as an array before you use it.

```
class price {

    public $anObjectVariable;

}

$prices = array();
$p = new price();
$p->anObjectVariable = "PRINT ME IN ERROR LOG!";
array_push($prices, $p);

for($i = 0; $i < count($prices); $i++){
    echo($prices[$i]->anObjectVariable);
}
```

Are you actually testing the code you show us above (i.e. the one I just posted above) or are you working on a derivative?  Can you confirm that this exact snippet above works for you correctly?

Comment: Is correct. Php throws a warning if the array doesn't already exist. OP, dial up the error reporting.

Comment: no, in the code on which I'm working $prices is passed in as a variable in a function but it is declared, I'm sure of that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure of it because if I var_dump($prices) right before the loop I can see the array correctly...

Comment: Well, then again, I ask:  Can you copy the code above and see if that one works for you.  Because if it does, then you might have the first clue why your other code doesn't work.

Comment: Got the error! I've solved the typo of $i just to see there was another one. Fixed, thanks!

Comment: Also, it is not very helpful to post some code on SO and say "it doesn't work", when you actually have different code that doesn't work.  Always post the exact code that "doesn't work", otherwise you are really keeping us in the dark.

Comment: you're right, but the original code is 500+ lines long. I always try to isolate the code and change some variables name to make it more clear.

Comment: That is completely OK to do... but then you should test that new trimmed down code locally first, before claiming it doesn't work.  And then post that new code exactly. But glad it got solved in the end. :)

Answer (score 2):

Then if it's not a typo

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($prices); $i++) {
    error_log($prices[$i]->anObjectVariable);
}
```

should work

Comment: I tried with you code and it worked... which one of the errors do you get with this?